# JNI c++ Netbeans Debugging

Tags: c++, eclipse, netbeans, java-native-interface

I have a java application that communicates with JNI C++ application. My java application is in eclipse while I am using netbeans for C++ with mingw64 bit compiler. I can not seem to debug JNI part of the application.

I load dll in java application. From netbeans I go to Debug->Attach Debugger select javaw.exe that makes my eclipse stuck and I get exception in eclipse IDE:

```
org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException. Timeout occurred while waiting for packet. occurred creating step request
```

Is my debugging procedure correct? How does one configure netbeans to debug a JNI application.

Answer (score 2):

This could be because your debugger is stopping all your threads when attaching, and not letting them resume properly afterwards (Not sure why this happens. It seems to only happen on some computers, and work fine on others).
A way to around this that worked for me is - In your C++ debugger configurations, in the debugger tab, tick the "Non-stop mode" checkbox. This will stop your debugger from stopping your threads, and the timeout should stop happening.